# NullPointerException setOnClickListener in a button using ActionBarSherlock fragments

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, onclicklistener, android-2.3-gingerbread

I'm very new to Android development, I'm trying to create a tabbed activity with the ABS so that i can use it with +10 API, I succeed so far. But my problem appeared when i tried to create a button in a fragment that launches another activity I've got a NullPointException. Here's my files.

 MainPaiement.java

```
package com.enhancedtechnologies.siclapplication.GestionPaiement;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;
import com.enhancedtechnologies.siclapplication.R;

public class MainPaiement extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

// Declare Variables
ActionBar mActionBar;
ViewPager mPager;
Tab tab;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get the view from activity_main.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_paiement);

    // Activate Navigation Mode Tabs
    mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    mActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Locate ViewPager in activity_main.xml
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    // Activate Fragment Manager
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

    // Capture ViewPager page swipes
    ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener ViewPagerListener = new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            super.onPageSelected(position);
            // Find the ViewPager Position
            mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    };

    mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(ViewPagerListener);
    // Locate the adapter class called ViewPagerAdapter.java
    ViewPagerAdapter viewpageradapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(fm);
    // Set the View Pager Adapter into ViewPager
    mPager.setAdapter(viewpageradapter);

    // Capture tab button clicks
    ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // Pass the position on tab click to ViewPager
            mPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    };

    // Create first Tab
    tab = mActionBar.newTab().setText("Nouveau Paiement").setTabListener(tabListener);
    mActionBar.addTab(tab);

    // Create second Tab
    tab = mActionBar.newTab().setText("Paiement         Effectu\u00e9").setTabListener(tabListener);
    mActionBar.addTab(tab);

}
}
```

### FragmentPaiementEffec.java

```
package com.enhancedtechnologies.siclapplication.GestionPaiement;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;
import com.enhancedtechnologies.siclapplication.R;


public class FragmentPaiementEffec extends SherlockFragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {



    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_paiement_rech, container, false);

// button chercher
    Button btnchercher = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button6);

    // this is Line 30


    btnchercher.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityPaiementrechercheResultat.class));
        }
    });
    return view;

}
}
```

### LogCat

```
07-27 20:30:32.264    1190-1190/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.enhancedtechnologies.siclapplication.GestionPaiement.FragmentPaiementEffec.onCreateView(FragmentPaiementEffec.java:29)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1789)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:955)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:490)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1105)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:951)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1473)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:581)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:365)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:531)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
        at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:839)
        at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

EDIT

### fragment_paiement_rech.xml ##

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFF1E1" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout9"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Recherche des taxes recouvrées"
                android:id="@+id/textView20"
                android:textColor="#FF6D2C20"
                android:textSize="35sp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
                android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Taxe"
                    android:id="@+id/textView15"
                    android:textColor="#FF6D2C20"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp" />

                <Spinner
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
                    android:background="#ffffc391" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout7"
                android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="CIN Redevable/Numéro de patente"
                    android:id="@+id/textView16"
                    android:textColor="#FF6D2C20"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="300dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:id="@+id/editText4"
                    android:background="#ffffc391" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout8"
                android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Du : "
                        android:id="@+id/textView18"
                        android:textColor="#FF6D2C20"
                        android:textSize="25sp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp" />

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="300dp"
                        android:layout_height="60dp"
                        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:id="@+id/editText5"
                        android:background="#ffffc391" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Période de paiement"
                    android:id="@+id/textView17"
                    android:textColor="#FF6D2C20"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Au : "
                        android:id="@+id/textView19"
                        android:textColor="#FF6D2C20"
                        android:textSize="25sp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp" />

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="300dp"
                        android:layout_height="60dp"
                        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:id="@+id/editText6"
                        android:background="#ffffc391" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                style="@style/styleButtons_port"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Chercher"
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:textSize="35sp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textColor="#ff000000" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I'll Be grateful if I get any sort of Help !!

Comment: Can you paste the code from fragment_paiement_rech layout file? It most probably seems like you haven't defined button6 in that layout file.

Comment: I already checked it. button6 exists in fragment_paiement_rech.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined button6 in fragment_redevable_rech but FragmentPaiementEffec is creating its view from fragment_paiement_rech, which is a different layout file. Your fragment should inflate fragment_redevable_rech.

Your fragment's onCreateView should have

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_redevable_rech, container, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your application cant find in the view stack the button6.
Assure that you created such view.
Try to debug and wach if this object exists before is reached.

Comment: I'm very new to this buddy ! I tried a debug I've got the same Error message !